# How do I select XML elements in this situation in VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, rss, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

So I have:

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>My channel</title>
        <item></item>
        <item></item>
        <item></item>
        <item></item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

When I use xmlDocument to parse it, I try to get all the item elements, but if I use

```
For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In xmlDocument.Item("rss").Item("channel")
```

It would give me 5 instead 4 results, since `<title>My Channel</title>` is considered one of the item under channel. I'm just wondering if there is anyway to loop through only the 4 item elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XPath expression to drilldown directly to elements you need. In your case it would be:

```
For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In XmlDocument.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item")
```